# Montgomery Multiplication Algorithm on Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pseudocode, montgomery-multiplication

I try Montgomery Multiplication Algorithm on Python 3.x. This algorithm pseudo-code is given below:

```
Input: Modulus N(n bit), gcd(n, 2) = 1, Multipler: A (n bit), Multiplicant: B (n bit)
Output: R = (A x B x 2 ^ (-n)) mod N

R = 0

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    q = (R + A(i) * B) mod 2
    R = (R + A(i) * B + q * N) / 2
}

print(R)
```

Python 3.x code that was written is given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

N = 41

A = 13

B = 17

n = N.bit_length()

R = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    q = int(R + (A & (1 << i) != 0) * B) % 2
    R = int((R + (A & (1 << i) != 0) * B + q * N) / 2)

print("Result:", R % N)
```

But, the code isn't given correct result. What is the problem?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: What result is it giving and what result are you expecting?

Comment: That code is giving result is 12.

Comment: The code is giving 12, but what number are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for 12. The code's result is 21.

Comment: The correct code's result is 31.

Comment: And 31 is what you should expect, no?

Comment: Number 41's bit length is 6. So, the result is 31.

Comment: Do you still think that there is something wrong with your code?

Comment: Number 41 is 101001 as binary.

Comment: Yes, 41 has bit-length 6. Do you still think something is wrong with your code? You never answered the question about what you expected the output to be.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see again your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your (modified) code I get 31, and 31 appears to be the right answer.

According to your pseudocode, `R` should be

```
R = (A x B x 2 ^ (-n)) mod N
```

In your case that is

```
R = (13*17*2^(-6))%41
```

The interpretation of `2^(-6)` when you are working mod 41 is to raise the mod 41 multiplicative inverse of 2 to the power 6, then take the result mod 41. In other words, `2^-6 = (2^-1)^6`.

Since 2*21 = 42 = 1 (mod 41), 2^(-1) = 21 (mod 41). Thus:

```
R = (13*17*2^-6) (mod 41)
  = (13*17*(2^-1)^6) (mod 41)
  = (13*14*21^6) (mod 41) 
  = 18954312741 (mod 41)
  = 31
```

which shows that the result is 31, the number returned by your code.
Thus your code is correct. If there is a clash between output and expectation, perhaps in this case the problem is one of expectation.

Comment: Sorry, n should be 6. I changed the my question's n variable's value.